# Data Virtualization and provisioning tools such as Delphix

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, virtualization

Our DB department is considering purchasing a Delphix license, and I'm wondering if there are any other tools that provide the same features. Features that we need in our work environment that are provided by delphix are:

- The ability to virtualize a whole database and store it in a sepearate server
- Compresses the database to 1/3 of its actual size
- gives the ability to use the compresses the database (in the delphix engine) without the need to clone the database to the target, instead, the engine provisions the compressed the db to the target in a matter of few minutes
- Any update made in the target are unique and do not affect the data in other targets
- All changes made are stored in the engine with the ability to rewind if needed

I looked into some tools such as informatica and Denodo bu I'm not an expert in the topic and can't tell whether they provide the same as Delphix or not.

Comment: You didn't say what database system you're using. Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: it applies to most RDBMS. We are considering it for Oracle and SQl Server.

Comment: Ah, okay. The company I work for, Redgate, has a database provisioning for SQL Server (called SQL Clone) but not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Denodo is a data virtualization tool, so does not mirror data (except for  caching).  It can provide a single point of interface and blend multiple data sources.  It has no 'rewind' capabilities'.

Informatica's most popular tool is Powercenter, an ETL/DWH tool. It won't store data, compress or rewind. There may be other Informatica solutions closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Colin for your answer. We went for Delphix and it's pretty decent.